# Call TypeAhead methods from TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to call TypeAhead library within a TypeScript module. How can I achieve a script similar to the follow one?

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts" />

$ReferrerSearchInput.typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: false,
    minLength: 3
},
{
    name: "Referrers",
    display: "DisplayValue",
    source: referrersDatasource,
    limit: 20,
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(data) {
            return data.FullName;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
const datasource = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: "MyUrl%QUERY",
        wildcard: "%QUERY"
    }
});

const inputOptions = {
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 0
};

const apiSettings = {
    name: "DisplayName",
    display: "Name",
    source: datasource,
    limit: 20,
    templates: {
        empty: "",
        suggestion(data: any) {
            return "";
        }
    }
};

$ReferrerSearchInput.typeahead(inputOptions, apiSettings);
```